# Network analyzing tools

Tags: networking, virtualization

I am doing a project in collage. My project is to compare two different simulators, one id GNS3 and the other OPNET. what I have to do is generate traffic through the simulators and measure it. I will be using the same network on both simulators. two switches and two routers with two nodes. Wireshark is a good tool, but I would like something more graphical if can get it.

Comment: Get a team together then, we wont show you how to pass.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of analyzing you want to perform, but I think getting a Kali Linux system (works also live) would be the best, as it contains by default numbers of tools for network analysis (even some of that kind that would be illegal to use if you don't own the network you perform it onto, or at least have permission to do so). I think the most famous app there for network analysis is wireshark.

Comment: OP is looking for analyzers for Ubuntu, i don't think suggesting him a whole different and advanced distro is helpful.

Comment: It also is based on debian, so the difference is not _that_ huge. But it is THE professional OS for network analyzing, so I thought at least it should be mentioned somewhere. I also suggested wireshark as a single application that is also available for Ubuntu!